# Vertically align content in a sidebar to references in the text [based on Tufte-style comments]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a long text (font size is adjustable so breaking it into parts beforehand is not really an option) with references in it ([1],[2],...) and the corresponding comments.

```
<div id="content>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<span id ="ref1">[1]</span> sadipscing elitr, 
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<span id ="ref2">[2]</span>
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<span id ="ref3">[3]</span>
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="com1">
    should be next to [1]
  </div>
  <div id="com2">
    should be next to [2]
  </div>
  <div id="com3">
    should be next to [3]
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to align the comments to the references in a pure HTML/CSS way or is Javascript needed? Backwards compatibility is not important.

The comments should always be visible and horizontally aligned.
As a bonus they should allow any form of content not just pure text.

Also keep in mind that two references could be next to each other so that the second comment gets pushed down a bit.

At this point I see no viable option other than JS.
If the font size was fixed, one could easily break down the text into divs and simply align them.

Comment: What about some kind of tooltip? The referenced text should be nested inside a hidden span along with the `[1]` in the text. Then using absolute positioning would work.

Comment: The sidenotes should always be visible and horizontally aligned. References can be anywhere in the line so they would need different offsets. But those offsets would depend on the font size.

Comment: some inspiration for what I try to get in HTML: http://slugmath.ucsc.edu/mediawiki/images/4/41/NumberTheory.pdf

Comment: Just for your information: These sidenotes (in a sidebar/column) are called marginalia. In your pdf, you're talking about something like on page 7, right?

Comment: Thanks for teaching me that term. Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

1) Add the sidebar text as a [data- attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

2) Display it in a absolutely positioned pseudo element using the [attr() CSS function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr).

3) You could then polish the result by switching the `<span>` elements with `<sup>` elements and

4) add CSS counters to dynamically generate the corresponding comment number to prefix each comment.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/B2JUr/10/)**

Try resizing the window width in the above fiddle !

### Markup

```
<sup data-comment="should be next to [1]" id ="ref1">[1]</sup>
```

### CSS

```
#content
{
    margin-right: 150px;
    counter-reset: section; /* Set the section counter to 0 */
}
sup
{
    font-size: 10px;
}
sup[data-comment]:before
{
    counter-increment: section; /* Increment the section counter */
    content: counter(section);  /* Display the counter */

    position: absolute;
    right:10px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 8px;
}
sup[data-comment]:after
{
    content: attr(data-comment);
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: how does this cope with two references in the same line?

Comment: @MalteSchledjewski This is a really hard requirement and I know of no way to achieve this with only CSS. So far his solutions looks pretty promising.

Comment: @MalteSchledjewski since each span has its own id - I guess you'll have to target those ones specially.